# Can't change label in programmatically generated UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, nib

I am trying to change the label with my programmatically loaded NIB. I created a class `MyView` which includes a `UILabel*` named `myLabel` but when I use `MyView` I cannot change `myLabel`:

**MyView.h**

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{
    UIView *view;
    UILabel *myLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

**MyView.m**

```
@implementation MyView
@synthesize myLabel, view;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
...
```

So when I initialize the `MyView`

```
UIView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
```

I cannot change the label as `myLabel` is not identified:

```
myView.myLabel.text = @"New Label Text";
```

I know there is some silly error in my logic or understanding of `UIView`.

Comment: "cannot change the label as myLabel is not identified:" - where? Do you have the two last lines at the same place in your code?

Comment: I understand my error - declared *myView as a UIView and not as MyView so I did not have access to properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare it as,

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
myView.myLabel.text = @"New Label Text";
```

If you use `UIView`, it is saying that it cannot find a property named `myLabel` in `UIView` class. Since you have declared this property in a subclass of `UIView`, you need to use the subclass name here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast myView to MyView since you declared it as a normal UIView. Try this:

```
((MyView *)self.myView).myLabel.text = @"New Label Text";
```

Or simply declare your myView as type MyView instead of UIView